# How to get a list of all the weather stations, in a given state, using wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, weather

I am currently working on making a 3D plot with Latitude on the x, Longitude on the y, and total rainfall during hurricane Harvey on the z.

The `weatherdata` function in wolfram `mathematica` requires you to pass in a name of a weather station as a parameter.

Is there a way to use the Entity or `EntityList` function to get a list off all the names of weather stations in a given state.

Comment: I think you need to grab all of them with `WeatherData[]` and search, although I dont readily see how to test if a given `GeoPosition` is in a given state. Suggest you try mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works, although there is probably a more direct way.  To find the weather stations in Illinois, for example, find the nearest 100 from Springfield, then select the ones in Illinois.

```
coordinates = CityData["Springfield", "Coordinates"];

weatherstations = WeatherData[{coordinates, 100}];

entityvalues = EntityValue[
   weatherstations, "PropertyAssociation"];

properties = {
     #[[Key[EntityProperty[
         "WeatherStation", "Name"]]]],
     #[[Key[EntityProperty[
         "WeatherStation", "Coordinates"]]]]} & /@
   entityvalues;

states = {GeoNearest["USState", Last[#]],
     First[#]} & /@ properties;

Last /@ Select[states, #[[1, 1]] == Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision",
     List["Illinois", "UnitedStates"]] &]
```

> {KCPS, KSAR, KBLV, KALN, KPPQ, KUIN, KCIR, KMDH, KMWA, K3LF}